# Mailing is saved but does not reach recipients

Tags: civimail, groups, smtp

I'm really out of my depth now.
Here is the situation:

CiviCRM version 5.36.0
Wordpress Plugin
Hosted on Linux Server

Administer->System Settings->Outbound Mail: enteredSMTP-Server, Testmail is sent and arrives at destination.

View Contact->Actions->Send an Email: Mail is sent and arrives at destination.

Mailings->New Mailing->Testgroup: shows 2 recipients.

Send test (single) 2nd try: Mail is sent and arrives at destination.

Send test (Testgroup - same as final recipients): Mail is sent and arrives at destination.

Next->Send immediately->Submit Mailing: Mailing is listed as scheduled, Email does not arrive at destination.

The Mailing report doesn't show any bounces.

I have tried different recipient addresses (two different test groups) on different mail services. I have tried with two different Mail providers for outbound mail. Everything works except the final mailing. I have no idea what else to test.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe not obvious but send immediately for mass mailings means "schedule it now". You need to set up the scheduled job that sends out mass mailings. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_process_mailing

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction. They really are the champions of hiding functions where you don't expect them.